# Assign more than 2 shape keys to same object bone

Tags: rigging, drivers, shape-keys

Initially I had 2 shape keys for my eyebrows which I used as a driver using a bone z location (-3*var and 3*var). This worked fine. But now I wanted to create a third shape key. So after that I added this key to the same driver bone using expression 6* var. But this does not work. Seems like only 2 shape keys work at a time using this setup. Can anyone explain it to me why so?

Thanks!

Comment: I think I could help if I knew more details. Could you link your .blend file?

Comment: Are you putting th driver on the shapeKey's influence? Also, what is the variable? Some variables don't play nice with drivers in the old (2.79) depsgraph (I think this is fixed in 2.8).